# Microsoft office automation error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, vb6

I am receiving an error when i try to create an excel workbook through a vb6 application. the error is a Microsoft Software Installer error 0x80004023. i have read over a similar question on a different site and tried the solution but it did not solve the problem. this is the other question [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/56edf118-891f-4ef1-b8ee-550a15bd1277/error-when-using-office-automation?forum=officeitproprevious#60965d20-072e-4680-964b-014a0b17dcd4).

i am wondering if i need to delete ALL the matching CSLID keys with the same code as the excel application because there is more than one location where the key is for excel, or if i need to delete all the CSLID keys for all the applications. its just not explained well in the other question.

Comment: Which OS are you trying to use it on? Which version and edition of Office? Has it ever worked as expected with this configuration?

Comment: its on windows 7, office 2010 64 bit. it has worked on windows 7 office 2013, however the code allows for this action to work on any office version.

Comment: If this is the first time you've tried to use it with the 64-bit Office, then that's most likely your problem.  MS recommends installing 32-bit Office even on 64-bit machines for similar reasons. Do you have the code to the VB6 program so you can debug it?

Comment: I have actually since repaired the office 2010 and apparently some of the registry keys were broken. it has fixed it and i can import information to excel.

Comment: Nice, you should post what you did as an answer for future visitors (you're allowed to answer your own questions)

Answer (score 1):

What i did to fix this problem was to delete all the keys in the registry linked to excel applications (found in the link in the question). i then repaired office and restarted the computer which fixed the problem and allowed me to create a workbook through visual basic.